# how to do 301 redirect to multiple pages

Tags: .htaccess

i have two websites,

both websites contains few pages, and wordpress blog, please following structure

```
www.firstwebsite.com
-Root
  -index.html
  -about.html
  -Blog
    -blog page1
    -blog page2

www.secondwebsite.com
-Root
  -index.html
  -about.html
  -Blog
    -blog page1
    -blog page2
```

now, I want to redirect all the blog pages (i.e. pages under blog folder) of www.firstwebsite.com to the www.secondwebsite.com/blog, using htaccess 301 redirect.

I know i can redirect like

```
Redirect 301 /a.html www.secondwebsite.com/blog
Redirect 302 /b.html www.secondwebsite.com/blog
```

but if there any simple way, so i can redirect all pages by writing just line in .htaccess file, as destination for all the pages is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `RewriteRule` for this

```
RewriteEngine On
# If the hostname for this request matches www.firstwebsite.com...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.firstwebsite\.com$ [NC]
# Redirect all requests in Blog/ to the equivalent on www.secondwebsite.com
RewriteRule Blog/(.*) http://www.secondwebsite.com/Blog/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

`RewriteCond` is a conditional match on the request's hostname. So above, we're only applying the rewrite to requests matching `www.firstwebsite.com`.  The `[NC]` on the end makes it a case-insensitive match.

The `RewriteRule` uses the expression `Blog/(.*)` to match all requests to the Blog directory, capturing everything after `/` in a match group.  The request is then rewritten into `www.secondwebsite.com/Blog` using the match from the request `(.*)` as `$1`, so the whole request comes out identically in `www.secondwebsite.com`.

Comment: i want to redirect all the pages that is inside 'Blog' folder of www.firstwebsite.com to the www.secondwebsite.com/blog, and i have nver used RewriteRule, so can you please explain me somewhat in detail

Comment: @mack see explanation added above.

Comment: `Blog vs blog`: It may not work correctly. I would write `RewriteRule` as: `RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://www.secondwebsite.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301,QSA,NC]` to make it ignore case comparison.

Comment: @anubhava i didn't get what you are saying, Blog vs blog? and why you have write $ after ^blog/(.*) ?, one more thing, what is L and QSA ?

Comment: *I misread your question*: It appeared to me that your blog directory name is `blog` not `Blog` (My apologies to @Michael). `$` denoted end of text. `L` - Last Rule, `QSA` for Query String Append.

Comment: hi friends, i have tried both `RewriteEngine On
# If the hostname for this request matches www.firstwebsite.com...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.firstwebsite\.com$ [NC]
# Redirect all requests in Blog/ to the equivalent on www.secondwebsite.com
RewriteRule Blog/(.*) http://www.secondwebsite.com/Blog/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]` and `RewriteEngine On
# If the hostname for this request matches www.firstwebsite.com...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.firstwebsite\.com$ [NC]
www.secondwebsite.com
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://www.secondwebsite.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301,QSA,NC]` but none them is worked :(